# posgresql return an aggregate from join if key exists on the corresponding table

Tags: postgresql, join, foreign-keys

I am trying to do a join operation and return an aggregate of a column from another table using the query below in posgres.

```
select users.username, users.id, string_agg(keys.service, ',') 
from users 
  join keys on keys.user_id = users.id 
where users.username = 'test' 
group by users.id
```

The query works well when there is a corresponding value in the `keys` table but it fails if there isn't and I would like it to return an empty string if the `keys` table doesn't have any values corresponding to the `id` from the `users` table

Comment: Use a LEFT join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` into `keys` to return `users` that have no corresponding row in `keys`.

Then, use `coalesce()` to convert `null` `keys.service` values to an empty string.

```
select users.username, users.id, 
       string_agg(coalesce(keys.service, ''), ',') 
  from users 
       left join keys 
              on keys.user_id = users.id 
 where users.username = 'test' 
 group by users.id
```